# How best to react to 5/5 badge getting stuck

Tags: bug

Picture attached:

[image: 5/5 Badge]

When I asked a question on Stack Overflow Meta I was told to just wait when things like this happen. I am happy to, but is this the best process?

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: Deleted youtube links. If you have something to say, you can type it out in words like the rest of us.

Answer (score 7):

[image]

Clicking on the next badge 'loading bar' tells you what's wrong.

"maintain a positive question record" - that criterion is not met. I see lots of zeros, and negative votes, and a few deletions.

So. Ask more good questions, which people upvote, and you'll get that badge

Comment: I checked it for you. According to your profile, that's why you don't have the badge.

Comment: Click on the brown bar, that should bring up a popup. THat should show what I'm seeing.

Comment: My guess would be it takes deleted questions into account, and even without those, your zero and negative vote questions outnumber the positive vote ones.

Comment: You might have forgotten. I see a few that are self deleted, and one that was not. They do exist tho.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek You might want to check this meta post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/278862/245360

Comment: Postive record is defined as `(total questions - negative questions - closed - deleted)/total questions >= 0.5` so includes closed and delete questions.

Comment: Correction: You have 5 **well received** questions (score >1). However, 2 of them **were posted on the same day** (March 27). The badge criteria is on 5 **separate** days.

Comment: Someone's nuttier than squirrel sh*t and for once it's not me.